# Double arrow in the outcome

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

Does anyone know how do I get rid of one of the double part at the start of the outcome `rh-> rh->`

```
rhdef = rh -> FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]
(* rh ->  rh -> ... *)
```

I want to use the outcome as an equation.

Comment: Why not take out the first one yourself when you define it, as in `rhdef = FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]` or even `rhdef = rh /. FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]` depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Thank you very much, that sounds very logical when I see both "=" signs explicitly (not in my mathematica screen). As you can see I'm kind of new in this. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know the form of the output for `FSol`, `RHS` or `vanhdef` because you have not provided that information, so we can only guess.

If `FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]` returns a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) for `rh`  (*i.e.* `Rule[rh,x]` or `rh->x`) then just use

```
rhdef = rh /. FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]
```

Here `/.` stands for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) so is the same as

```
rhdef = ReplaceAll[rh, FSol[RHS[vanhdef] == 0, rh]]
```

Notice that a rule is just a [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) with value `Rule` and two elements, any of which you can get with [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) as well

```
FullForm[a -> b]
```

> ```
> Rule[a,b]
> ```

```
(a->b)[[2]]
```

or

```
Part[a->b,2]
```

> ```
> b
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of details, though you've interpreted me well. Thank you very much for your prompt reply, very helpful.

Comment: @Kid. Since you found this reply helpful, you should indicate your appreciation by accepting this answer. You can do that by click on the check mark that appears below down arrow on the lefthand side of the answer.